# How to catch pg8000.core.IntegrityError exception in python?

Tags: python, postgresql, pg8000

I am trying to run a test case to catch an primary key exception when trying to load into a table in postgresql using **pg8000**. But, I'm unable to catch it in python. Below is my code.

```
import pg8000

def create_albums(self,music):
    experts = []
    exp = music.data_info.get("artist_list")  # List of a dictionary
    try:
        for expert in exp:
            experts.append(ArtistData({
                "name": expert.name,
                "age": expert.age,
                "present": True,
                "nodiscs": expert.get("disc_code")
                }))
    except pg8000.core.IntegrityError:
        raise Exception
    return experts
```

Below is the error message

```
pg8000.core.IntegrityError: {'S': 'ERROR', 'V': 'ERROR', 'C': '23505', 'M': 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "artist_discs_pkey"}
```

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What exactly happens when you run your code?

Comment: So the (Primary Keys)PK's are the name and disc_code. When I have the same name and same disc_code. It issues a 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint.'

Answer (score 1):

You do catch the exception, but all you do is raise it again, so it's rather useless.

Add a simple print before the raise, eg. `print("Failed to insert")`, and you'll see that message followed by the exeption that raised it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://pybrary.net/pg8000/errors.html),

"pg8000.core.IntegrityError:" Belongs to the generic (*DatabaseError*). So you would need to format your code like this replacing IntegrityError with DatabaseError:

```
import pg8000

def create_albums(self,music):
    experts = []
    exp = music.data_info.get("artist_list")  # List of a dictionary
    try:
        for expert in exp:
            experts.append(ArtistData({
                "name": expert.name,
                "age": expert.age,
                "present": True,
                "nodiscs": expert.get("disc_code")
                }))
    except pg8000.core.DatabaseError:
        raise Exception
    return experts
```